# How to set mime type to html in camel for emailing to outlook

Tags: apache-camel, html-email, content-type, camel-ftp

I have been trying to set the mime type in a java class using camel with the following code

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,"text/html");
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(emailBody);
```

but the generate mail is of type text/plain.Any help would appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The content-type is just a header, it does not transform the message body etc. So you should make sure the `emailBody` is in xml.

If you enable TRACE level logging on Camel it logs what the content type it is using

```
        LOG.trace("Using Content-Type {} for MimeMessage: {}", contentType, part);
```

So maybe try to enable TRACE logging and see what it logs. And double check that your `emailBody`is already in XML Format.